# Check which page called this php?

Tags: php

Here is what I'm dealing with:

Let's say I have some php page:

```
<?php
    // do php stuff
?>
```

And I have two HTML pages where the action sends them to this php page. On this php page, I want it to do one thing if it comes from one of the html pages, and something else if it comes from the other. I cannot pass any explicit variables to the php page, I need to check which page called the php.

I have tried:

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` when I access this, it doesn't seem the send the referring page.
`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` this gives the previous page to the one im looking for.

For example:

`HTML PAGE1` form calls `php` page --> I want some variable in PHP that contains `HTML PAGE1`.
`HTML PAGE2` form calls `php` page --> I want some variable in PHP that contains `HTML PAGE2`.

Thanks for the help. Please let me know if there's some way I can clarify the question.

Comment: So if $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] worked what's the question?

Comment: it didn't work. It seems to provide the page previous to the one i'm looking for.

Comment: Just change the form action to `mypage.php?from=page1` and `mypage.php?from=page2` and in your mypage.php you can get the page info like `$page = $_GET['from']` if the method is post. Otherwise add a hidden field called `from` and put values as mentioned above.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent 'I cannot pass any explicit variables to the PHP page' would stop that being viable.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent Thanks for the answer. I know I can do that, but as I stated in the question, I'd like to do this without explicitly passing any additional variables.

Comment: Can you use a cookie or a session variable instead?

Comment: sorry I missed that line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the domain differs you can use:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

But in all scenarios this would help:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Giving you the complete URL that was called.

Comment: This will give the URI and host of the current page, not the URI and host of the page that called it.

Comment: That is how I read the question, otherwise HTTP_REFERER would have worked for him.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, no the domain does not differ. I will read about `_URI`

Comment: @PassKit If `HTTP_REFERER` did what the asker required then this question wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

As Think Different said a hidden field in your form is probably your best bet because you don't want to modify the url. In this case you would have the form submit over a POST request and retrive your data with `$page = $_POST['YOUR_HIDDEN_VARIABLE_HERE']`.

Comment: Note that this will require some Javascript on the initiating pages to cancel the GET request and submit a POST request in it's place.

Comment: Well he is already preforming a POST request because he's using a form action and not modifying the url (or at least that's how i read it)